# Passing standard data through serviceprovider

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5. To pass the users his favorites and permalink, I edited the `AppServiceProvider`. I was wondering if my solution is the most reasonable solution.

Of particular concern is future extensibility in terms of adding additional views.  I only have the two now but I think it's quite possible that I'll add more in the future.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Models\Favorites;
use Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('navigation.top-menu-only', function($view) {
            $this->getData($view);
        });

        view()->composer('navigation.menu', function($view) {
            $this->getData($view);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * This service provider is a great spot to register your various container
     * bindings with the application. As you can see, we are registering our
     * "Registrar" implementation here. You can add your own bindings too!
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
            'App\Services\Registrar'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get data for menu
     * 
     * @param  object $view
     * 
     * @return view
     */
    private function getData($view)
    {
        if (Auth::Check()) {
            $favoritesModel = new Favorites();
            $companiesModel = new Companies();
            $messagesModel = new MessagesSend();

            $favorites = $favoritesModel->getFavorites();
            $company = $companiesModel->findByUserId(Auth::User()->id);
            $unreadMessages = $messagesModel->countRecivedUnreadedMessages();
            $lastMessages = $messagesModel->getRecivedMessages(Auth::User()->id, 5);

            $view->with('permalink', Auth::User()->permalink)
                 ->with('favorites', $favorites)
                 ->with('company', $company)
                 ->with('unreadMessages', $unreadMessages)
                 ->with('lastMessages', $lastMessages);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.